# Converting loops to async in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have the following sync function:

```
               for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var key1 = results[i]['__key'];
                        for (var j = i + 1; j < results.length; j++) {
                            var key2 = results[j]['__key'];
                            if (key1 == key2) {
                                for (var k = 0; k < results[i].length; k++) {
                                    for (var z = 0; z < results[j].length; z++) {
                                        if (results[i][k][key1] == results[j][z][key2]) {
                                            results[i][k] = lodash.extend(results[j][z], results[i][k]);
                                            results[j].splice(z, 1);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Can I change all the 4 loops to async? I'm not sure if the first two loops can be synced! Can I? I have tried to change the last two loops to async, but it is not giving me the right result? Could you please help me  how I can change my sync loops to async ones?

My attempt:

```
             for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var key1 = results[i]['__key'];
                for (var j = i + 1; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var key2 = results[j]['__key'];
                    if (key1 == key2) {
                        async.each(results[i], function (resultA, callback) {

                            async.each(results[j], function (resultB, callback) {
                                if (resultA[key1] == resultB[key2]) {
                                    resultA = lodash.extend(resultB, resultA);
                                    results[j].splice(resultB, 1);
                                }
                                callback();
                            }, function (err) {
                                callback(err);
                            }), function (err) {
                                callback(err);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
```

The complete algorithm:

```
        async.map(models, getData, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(400, err);
            } else {

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var key1 = results[i]['__key'];
                    for (var j = i + 1; j < results.length; j++) {
                        var key2 = results[j]['__key'];
                        if (key1 == key2) {

                            for (var k = 0; k < results[i].length; k++) {
                                for (var z = 0; z < results[j].length; z++) {
                                    if (results[i][k][key1] == results[j][z][key2]) {
                                        results[i][k] = lodash.extend(results[j][z], results[i][k]);
                                        results[j].splice(z, 1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                var mergedResult = [];
                mergedResult = mergedResult.concat.apply(mergedResult, results);
                res.json(200, mergedResult);
            }
        });


        function getData(model, next) {
            var data = db.getData(model.type, function (err, data) {
                data['__key'] = db.getKey(model.type).toString();
                next(err, data);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Changing the original code you have to async is not going to buy you anything. If anything, changing it to be async could introduce more latency. Just keep it the way it is if it's already working for you.

Comment: if the intention is to make your code "flatter" so that it doesnt become http://callbackhell.com/ you could break out your loops into functions that pass parameters between them as needed. This should help with alleviating some of the indent/deep nesting you've got

Comment: Depending on how many items are being iterated over, going async will buy you a **lot**. Nothing blocks in Node except your own code. Deeply nested loops like this can block for a noticeable amount of time, and that will prevent anything else in your app from happening.

Comment: I can't help but think there is a better way to solve your actual problem. Where is the data coming from and what does it actually look like? Can you modify the data before it gets to this result? For example, if you could aggregate the items so that all the objects with the same __key are grouped together, you could remove one of your loops and comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :) I put the complete algorithm in my question now! It is inside async.map... data (result of async.map) is an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem based on your code. It looks like you're iterating over an array of models, and grabbing all of their data based on the type. Then you go through the effort of merging the arrays if the type is the same. However `db.getData()` should return the same results if you pass in the same type, so there shouldn't be anything to merge later.

Based on my understanding of your problem, something like this would get you the results you're looking for without all the loop mess.

```
var results = {};

async.each(models, getData, function(err) {
  res.json(200, results);
});

function getData(model, next) {
  var key = db.getKey(model.type).toString();

  if(results[key]) {
    return next();
  }

  db.getData(model.type, function (err, data) {
    results[key] = data;
    next(err);
  });
}
```

You only grab the data from that model.type if you haven't retrieved it already. Then there is nothing to merge, and you can just return that data.

Comment: "Then you go through the effort of merging the arrays if the type is the same." No, if they key is the same not type!

Comment: You're getting the key for the first comparison from the model.type. `data['__key'] = db.getKey(model.type).toString();`.